# How do I investigate "macOS wants to make changes"

Tags: security, keychain, administrator

Every now and then a window pops up:

[image]

I hit `deny`, it reappears, I hit `deny` again, and, after 2-4 repetitions, I am left alone.

I wonder if there is a way to figure out what is going on - is there something malicious going on? a virus?

PS. I have no idea why [<kbd>Shift + Command + 4 + Space bar</kbd>](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201361) only captured *half* of the window.

Comment: Skype is generating the alert.  See the icon?

Comment: Lovely, let's see if this will stop now. Thank you!

Comment: What I usually see is something like "Slack wants to install a helper app". After this I need to restart Slack for it to self-update.